# File Compare between files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am planning to build a script for pre & post health check of my JVM & filesystem for that 
I want to compare 2 files pre.txt & post.txt and want to ignore what are the common lines in file1 and file2 display only what are the lines exist in pre.txt apart from common as a file final.txt .

useing comm command but not working 
Ex:--

**pre.txt**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            966M     0  966M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  1.2M  199M   1% /run
/dev/sda2        20G  6.1G   13G  33% /
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop2       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

**post.txt**

```
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop2       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
```

**final.txt**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            966M     0  966M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  1.2M  199M   1% /run
/dev/sda2        20G  6.1G   13G  33% /
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: see `diff --help`

Comment: diff didn't help it is possible on comm but i m missing some where

Comment: `comm` requires sorted inputs -- I don't think it's what you want.

Comment: You want to show just the lines that are unique to pre.txt?

Comment: `--suppress-common-lines` does not do it? (can not test because i am on busybox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grep to exclude the lines from `post.txt`:

```
$ grep -vxFf post.txt pre.txt 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            966M     0  966M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  1.2M  199M   1% /run
/dev/sda2        20G  6.1G   13G  33% /
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

- `-v`: inverts grep's matching behavior to exclude matching lines
- `-x`: only match whole lines
- `-F`: interpret the patterns as literal strings rather than regular expressions
- `-f`: specifies a file (`post.txt`) containing the patterns to match

Comment: Shouldn't we also use `-F`, sice the columns _Size_,  _Used_ and _Avail_ contain regexp characters? With your command, a `5.2M` in post.txt would match a `502M` in pre.txt, what is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, nice catch.